# Time complexity of this combination algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I was implementing a combinations algorithm. This should generate unique combinations of length from the given list .

For example:

```
Input list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with k = 3
should generate output

    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 4]
    [1, 2, 5]
    [1, 3, 4]
    [1, 3, 5]
    [1, 4, 5]
    [2, 3, 4]
    [2, 3, 5]
    [2, 4, 5]
    [3, 4, 5]
```

The working python code is given below for reference.

```
def my_combinations(items, k, out):
    if k==0:
        print out
        return

    for i in range(len(items)):
        new_out = out[:]
        new_out.append(items[i])
        my_combinations(items[i+1:], k-1, new_out)
```

**Question:**

What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

I started with the recurrence equation.

```
Base case: T(n, 0) = 1
Recurion : T(n, k) = T(n-1, k-1) + T(n-2, k-1) + T(n-3, k-1) + .. + T(0, k-1) + 1
                   = n * T(n-1, k-1) + 1
```

T(n) = ???

solution by expansion.

This question is different from the [Complexity when generating all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120402/complexity-when-generating-all-combinations).

My question is about the time complexity of the given implementation and the link question talks about runtime of generating all combinations in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complexity when generating all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120402/complexity-when-generating-all-combinations)

Comment: How is this actually different from the number of combinations itself (as the other question suggests)? You are making O(1) operations (basically an append call) for each single combination, hence the complexity is exactly the number of combinations.

Comment: @jdesha I am interested in getting the complexity for this implementation. Also, concern here is the recurrence relation representation of the recursion function and expansion to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @Michael Foukarakis for pointing the missing K.

```
Base case: T(n, 0) = 1
Recurion : T(n, k) = T(n-1, k-1) + T(n-2, k-1) + T(n-3, k-1) + .. + T(0, k-1) + 1
                   = n * T(n-1, k-1) + 1
```

Expanding it as below

```
T(n, k) = n * T(n-1, k-1) + 1
        = n * (n-1) * T(n-2, k-2) + 1 + 1
        = n * (n-1) * T(n-2, k-2) + 2
        = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * T(n-3, k-3) + 3

        ...

         = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ..(n-k) T(n-k, k-k) + k
         = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ..(n-k) (1) + k
         = O(n^k)  (As it is a k th order polynomial)
```

Overall we can say **O(n<sup>k</sup>)** runtime.

Comment: How does your answer take into account `k`? Where does "2" come from?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I have modified the answer to account for k. Let me know if there is a flaw in the derivation.

Comment: Your recurrence formula is wrong. Try to think about exactly what happens in each call/iteration.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I have modified the answer to account for k. Let me know if there is a flaw in the recurrence definition and derivation.