# time complexity of an algorithm which randomly pick m numbers from n numbers

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, combinations

1. There are n numbers. It was split into two parts. Each belongs one of the parts. Fetch m numbers to pair with a given number B. With p pick numbers from the first part, 1-p from the next part. Implemented it as **loop  flow**.

```
first pick a number in n. marked as B.
while (pick m numbers)
    r <- random()
    if p <= r then
        while (1)
            randomly pick a number from the first n/2 numbers
            if (never picked before and not equal to B) then
                picked successful
                break
            end if
        end while
     else if p > r
        while (1)
            randomly pick a number from the other n/2 numbers
            if (never picked before and not equal to B) then
                 picked successful
                 break
           end if
        end while
     end if
end while
```

The time complexity.

Is it  `m * (mp, n/2) + m * (m(1-p), n/2) = m * (n/2)! * (1/((mp)!(n/2-mp)!) * (1/((m(1-p))!(n/2-m(1-p))!)`?

What is a combination complexity? `O((n/2)!/((mp)!(n/2-mp)!)`.  Maybe this program is not combination complexity. I have no clues about it.

---

2. If the numbers are not split into two parts, which means that pick m numbers from n numbers. Is it same with above in time complexity?

```
first pick a number in n. marked as B.
while (pick m numbers)
    while (1)
        randomly pick a number from the n numbers
        if (never picked before and not equal to B) then
            pick successful
            break
        end if
    end while
end while
```

The time complexity.

Is it `m * (m, n)= m * n!/m!(n-m)!`? What is `O(n!/m!(n-m)!)`?

If `m=1`, `O(n!/m!(n-m)!)=O(n)` or `O(n!/m!(n-m)!)=O(n)=O(1)` ?

If `m=2`, `O(n!/2!(n-2)!)=O(1/2 n(n-1))=O(n^2)`? But it may only run twice and get the two right number, so why not `O(2)`? And if there is a number that has been picked before. You have to put it back and then pick again. So that it may run three times? So `O(n^2)` is the average time complexity? What is the worst one?

If `m<<n`, `O(n!/m!(n-m)!)` close to `O(n)` or `O(n!/m!(n-m)!) ~ O(n) ~ O(1)` ?

I am confusing about the time complexity. Can you help me to analyse it? There are [recurrence ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120402/complexity-when-generating-all-combinations). But I did not understand well in my `loop` case.

[[doc 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302623/time-complexity-of-this-combination-algorithms?noredirect=1&lq=1)] [[doc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120402/complexity-when-generating-all-combinations)] get all combinations. **I need only get one of the combinations, not all of them**.

Thank you.

Comment: There are few algorithms that are so bad they have factorial time complexity. There are far fewer problems still that *require* a factorial time complexity algorithm. Re-examine the problem, which *seems* to be straightforward enough to require nothing worse than O(n log n), but I can’t tell because the problem definition is unclear (to me, anyway).

Comment: The current algorithm is now I used. But I am not sure how to calculate the time complexity. In my case, m far less than n (m<<n). It might not factorial time complexity or combination complexity. But I don't know what it is. The second algorithm is easy. Just pick m numbers from n. But I don't know the time complexity. Both algorithms work for me.